# Feedback: C++ developers who've switched to VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, development-environment

I'm considering moving our shop over to VS2010 from VS2008sp1.  I've been very happy with 2008, but would like to make use of TR1 in our code.

---

**I'm really interested in fellow programmers gestalt of 2010 v. 2008, rather than the solution to any one element of the following!**

---

However, I'm in the process of converting our projects & solutions, and I'm finding that the "noise to signal" ratio is rather lame, IMO.  So far, I'm looking at rewiring every single project we have to get rid of the various apparently spurious Microsoft Build warnings, such as $(TargetExt) ... does not match the Linker's OutputFile property value ...

There are several variations on this message, several per project, and we have around 75 projects.  I have little or no desire to waste my time redoing all of these projects output targets (Apparently MSBuild insists that the linker's target and the compiler's target be identical, which is neither necessary nor desirable for us).

Additionally, [embarrassment], we still use VSS.  And just in my initial dealings with trying to massage the projects to compliance with MSBuild, I'm finding that the VSS interface in VS2010 is about 1/4 as fast as in 2008.  It's atrocious (and I'm used to the relatively lame performance of VSS in general).

Sigh... I know about 1/2 or more of the "answers" are going to be "Stop using VSS."  Yeah, that's a great idea, and we may migrate to subversion in the not too distant future.  But one thing at a time.  That only solves the VSS speed issue, not the MSBuild problems, nor the new C++ problems.

It seems that the new standard libraries and TR1 stuff has broken some of our code.  That's not in itself too shocking - I'd have been surprised if that weren't the case.  But as it stands, the error messages are LOOOONNNNNGGGG - it reminds me of my early days of trying to use the STL and having to load an error string parser helper that deduced the higher-level names for me so that the error messages could become somewhat useful.  Now, 10 years later, I'm back to seeing diagnostics so deep and convoluted that they make no sense, and I have no idea what the real issue is.  In one case I'm attempting to insert a new element in a multimap:

```
typedef CCimexDataSource::CategoryID                        CategoryID;
typedef std::multimap<CString, CCimexDataSource *>          description_sources_multimap;
typedef std::map<CategoryID, description_sources_multimap>  category_sources_map;
// attempt to insert a new description->CCimexDataSource* keyed by CategoryID (an unsigned)
m_category_sources_map[it->GetCategory()].insert(std::make_pair(it->GetDescription(), &(*it)));
```

And I get:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(163): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const CCimexDataSource *' to 'CCimexDataSource *'
1>          Conversion loses qualifiers
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(255) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base<_Ty,const CCimexDataSource>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const CString,
1>              _Ty2=CCimexDataSource *,
1>              _Ty=ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,
1>              _Other1=ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,
1>              _Other2=const CCimexDataSource *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory(208) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>,const CCimexDataSource*>(std::pair<ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>,const CCimexDataSource *> &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const CString,
1>              _Ty2=CCimexDataSource *,
1>              BaseType=char,
1>              StringTraits=StrTraitMFC<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory(280) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct<std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>>(std::pair<const _Kty,CCimexDataSource> *,_Other &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::pair<const CString,CCimexDataSource *>,
1>              _Ty1=ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,
1>              _Ty2=const CCimexDataSource *,
1>              _Kty=CString,
1>              _Other=std::pair<ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,const CCimexDataSource *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(592) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Cons_val<std::allocator<_Ty>,_Ty,std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>>(_Alloc &,std::pair<const _Kty,CCimexDataSource> *,std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::pair<const CString,CCimexDataSource *>,
1>              _Ty1=ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,
1>              _Ty2=const CCimexDataSource *,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const CString,CCimexDataSource *>>,
1>              _Kty=CString
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xtree(755) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_nod<_Traits>::_Node *std::_Tree_val<_Traits>::_Buynode<_Ty>(_Valty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<CString,CCimexDataSource *,std::less<CString>,std::allocator<std::pair<const CString,CCimexDataSource *>>,true>,
1>              _Ty=std::pair<ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,const CCimexDataSource *>,
1>              _Valty=std::pair<ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,const CCimexDataSource *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\map(364) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert<_Ty>(_Valty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<CString,CCimexDataSource *,std::less<CString>,std::allocator<std::pair<const CString,CCimexDataSource *>>,true>>>,
1>              _Ty2=bool,
1>              _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<CString,CCimexDataSource *,std::less<CString>,std::allocator<std::pair<const CString,CCimexDataSource *>>,true>,
1>              _Ty=std::pair<ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,const CCimexDataSource *>,
1>              _Valty=std::pair<ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,const CCimexDataSource *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\steve\projects\cimex cad-cam\14.0\cimex application\cimcad\formaddautomaticpage.h(17) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree> std::multimap<_Kty,_Ty>::insert<std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>>(_Valty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Mytree=std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<CString,CCimexDataSource *,std::less<CString>,std::allocator<std::pair<const CString,CCimexDataSource *>>,true>>,
1>              _Kty=CString,
1>              _Ty=CCimexDataSource *,
1>              _Ty1=ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,
1>              _Ty2=const CCimexDataSource *,
1>              _Valty=std::pair<ATL::CStringT<char,StrTraitMFC<char>>,const CCimexDataSource *>
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(163): error C2439: 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second' : member could not be initialized
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const CString,
1>              _Ty2=CCimexDataSource *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(167) : see declaration of 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=const CString,
1>              _Ty2=CCimexDataSource *
1>          ]
```

Note: the above appears to be a change in how std::set<> works, such that they always give back const_iterators instead of iterators(1).  But the point is just to have an example of how much more convoluted the compiler diagnostics are compared to 2008.

---

**So, my question: for any c++ shops out there that have converted recently: do you regret the conversion, or appreciate it?  How so?**

(1) Scott Meyer's "Effective STL", (c) 2001, p95, item 22.

I just ran into this: it covers many of the code-breaking changes I've been running into:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/25/stl-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-2010-beta-1.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: "I've been very happy with 2008, but would like to make use of TR1 in our code." <-- 2008 SP1 supports TR1... Also, if you post the error message in a codebox it would be a lot easier for us to decypher it...

Comment: Hint: When debugging compile errors, turn off parallel make.  Having lines from multiple build processes interleaved makes an already confusing task nearly impossible.  Then, focus on the first line of the error message.  Only if your response to that is "yeah, I know you (the compiler) can't do that.  Why are you trying to do that?" would you look at the context dump.

Comment: In this case, it says you need a write-capable `CCimexDataSource *` but provided a readonly `const CCimexDataSource *`.  Is `it` some sort of `const_iterator`?

Comment: The problem isn't VS2010, it's your code.  So you got away with an illegal construct for a while...now it's time to pay the piper.

Comment: "const_iterators instead of iterators" <- nope, std::set always had const_iterator and iterator to be the same const_iterator. Because you cannot modify a member of the set.

Comment: sigh- I'm obviously going to have to alter our code.  But the fact of the matter is you could always modify a member of a set so long as its sort-ordering didn't change.  There are discussions of it in Herb Sutter's books as well as in Scott Meyers.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: This is no problem when using the VS2010 GUI. You can order the build output by projects by selecting "Build - Order" in the dorp down box named "Show output from" on top of the Output Window.

Comment: @Gene - I found this: In C++98/03, you could get away with modifying set/multiset elements as long as you didn't change their ordering.  (Actually changing their ordering is definitely crashtrocity, breaking the data structure's invariants.)

C++0x rightly decided that this was really dangerous and wrong.  Instead, it flat-out says that "Keys in an associative container are immutable" (N2857 23.2.4/5) and "For [set and multiset], both iterator and const_iterator are constant iterators".

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: Type of `&(*it)` is probably `const CCimexDataSource *`, and not `CCimexDataSource *`.

To give input on your second discussion-question:
We have converted from VS2008 to VS2010, and it has worked out fine, although VS2010 is slower, it has a bit better intellisense. The conversion wasn't fully automatic, and we had to manually update the vcxproj files afterward.

Comment: Yes it is.  That solves the one C++ issue I presented, but I'm hoping for more insight into 2010.  For example: Set seems to have changed to force all of its iterators to be const_iterators, even when you explicitly use my_set::iterator.  And the diagnostics are, in my opinion so far, far less readable than 2008's.  Is this a shallow learning curve, worth it?  Or is it the tip of the iceberg, and massive learning curve & changes will be required for our software to come into compliance?

Comment: @Mordachai: You can't use `mycontainer::iterator` s if you passed the container by `const` reference. I.e. `const std::vector<t>::begin()` returns a `const_iterator`, not an `iterator`.

Comment: Modifying objects in-place which are stored in a `set` has always broken the set invariants.  You need to remove the old value and insert the new value, so that it will be found under the new hash.

Comment: @Billy - thanks, but even if the code is: CCimexDataSourceManager::iterator it = m_data_manager.begin(); I get the same error.  And I am getting similar errors everywhere in our code that uses std::set.  It seems that sets are now forced to give back const_iterator instead of iterator?  A TR1 change?

Comment: @Billy: It's more fundamental than that... iterators on `set` dereference as read-only, you can insert and remove elements but you can't modify them in-place, due to the hashtable structure of the `set` container.

Comment: @Ben - thanks - that clears up why the std::sets are a problem now (and didn't used to be).  Our code is careful to not change the hash-value of the entity even though we modify other parts of it.  I'll just have to const_cast such interactions.

Comment: @Mordachai: You might want to use the `mutable` modifier for members that don't affect the hash-value.

Comment: @Mordachai: don't use const_cast, you are creating a fragile code, one day somebody will break that set. If you need modifiable values, don't use std::set, that's what std::map is for.

Comment: @Ben - that's a thought.  I'm not at all happy that TR1 std::set forces me to alter my code to fit the TR1 teams' ideals.  My objects already have a clearly defined const/non-const which has nothing to do with their ID (which remains consistent across all changes).

Comment: @Gene - I'm sure that was the TR1's thought-model as well.  You/they are wrong.  It's entirely possible to build an object who's identity & ordering is consistent, even though the object remains modifiable.  Nothing fragile about that, if done correctly.  To the point: one cannot modify an existing CCimexDataSource in any way that would modify its ID, and thence its set-ordering.  So robust, and impossible for a future programmer to mess up short of completely altering the behavior of the class overall (i.e. no usage scenario which is fragile).

Answer (score 1):

At work, we moved from VS2005 to VS2010 with no problems.  However, I found that on my home computer, I had to turn off many of the Intellisense features in VS2010 as it was eating up so much processing power on my laptop that I could only type out a few characters at a time before having to wait 3 minutes for it to update its database.  If you are running on a fairly new machine (Quad-core ~3 GHz with at least 6 GB RAM) on Windows 7, you should have few performance problems.  If you (like I am at home), use a Core2 Duo with 2 GB RAM on XP, you'll find that you have to turn off many features for the IDE to be useful.

NOTE:  VS2008 ran wonderfully on my laptop; I was rather disappointed when I "upgraded".

Comment: may be you need to buy a new and more powerful laptop.

Comment: @Lemuel:  I agree, however I can't justify the funds for it while also building a new high-powered desktop (which is under construction at the moment).  There are lots of complaints about running VS2010 (especially the express edition) on XP (which has to run with less than 4GB of RAM).  Intellisense being the primary cause of the problem.  Disabling it makes the product usable, though VS2008 did not have this issue at all, so it is more of a hack to get the newer software to run rather than an actual remedy to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem on my home PC (Core2Duo E6600, 2 GB RAM) with intellisense. The only thing i don't like is the responsiveness of the UI. It's very sluggish.

I believe the improvements in TR1 and C++0x outweight the drawbacks of the slow UI.

Answer (score 1):

I tried converting our solution (VS2005) with 100 projects and after all the failures to update the project files I decided to give up for the time being as I couldn't even get it to start compiling.

Using VS2010 for new .net projects I find the IDE tries to be a bit more like Eclipse, but it keeps doing dopey things like opening code files in the view portion I last clicked on - say the output or watch variables windows.

Every so often I have trouble with the MS symbol servers, the debug/module feature to specifically go to the MS symbol server seems to get around this somehow and saves time messing with the symbol server list.